# Multiple setTimeouts on Nodejs

Tags: node.js, timer, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to implement an auto order cancel feature in my app. So i'm thinking of adding setTimeouts on Node which will cancel the user's order on a given time.

I tried adding the timer in the app but there's too much constraints.

Will multiple setTimeouts slow down the performance of our server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Agenda instead of setTimeouts.

Agenda uses a MongoDB database to persist scheduled tasks(and the parameters needed for the task) so that even if the server goes down, the tasks will still run at the specified time or intervals.

References :

https://thecodebarbarian.com/node.js-task-scheduling-with-agenda-and-mongodb

https://medium.com/hacktive-devs/nodejs-scheduling-tasks-agenda-js-4b6824f9457e

Answer (score 1):

> Will multiple setTimeouts slow down the performance of our server?

No, it won't slow it down any more so than the CPU time used when each timer runs.

The timer design in node.js is specifically built to manage large numbers of timers well.  There should be no issue with having lots of timers (tens of thousands would be fine).  There's a sorted list of timers and it only uses an actual OS level timer or the "next" timer event to fire.  When that fires, it grabs the next event in the list and sets an OS level timer for that one.  When a new timer is created, it is inserted into the sorted list and if it's not now the first timer in the list, it will just wait its turn until it is the first one in the list.

That said, you may not actually "need" a separate timer for each order.  Since you don't need millisecond or even minute level accuracy, you could maintain a list of unfinished orders with a timestamp for when they were last modified and then you could have a single interval timer that runs every several minutes that just checks which orders have exceeded your inactive time and should be cancelled.  If the order list was sorted by its timestamp, you'd just check a few orders from the end until you found ones that no longer need to be cancelled.